# Performance Counter value not set on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, performance-monitor

After creating new performance counter that works on windows 7 development machine, the setting of the Raw Value will not work when deployed to windows server 2012 R2.

The existing counters in the custom category all still work, but the new ones will not set.

I have tried deleting the entire category and recreating all the counters, but it still has the same outcome of the new counters not being set.

```
const string counterCategoryName = "Statistics";

var requiredCounters = GetAllCounters();

// Check counters exist
PerformanceCounterCategory category = null;
if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(counterCategoryName) == false // Category exists
    || !requiredCounters.All(counter =>
        PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()
            .Single(z => z.CategoryName == counterCategoryName)
            .CounterExists(counter.Name))) // All counters exist
{
    if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(counterCategoryName))
    {
        // This occurs in case there is a counter missing, we should delete the existing category and rebuild it with all the new counters
        PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(counterCategoryName);
    }

    var counterDatas = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

    foreach (var counter in requiredCounters.Select(counterDesc => new CounterCreationData
    {
        CounterName = counterDesc.Name,
        CounterHelp = counterDesc.Description,
        CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64 //counterDesc.Type
    }))
    {
        counterDatas.Add(counter);
    }

    category = PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(counterCategoryName, "Statistics",PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, counterDatas);
}
else
{
    category = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()
        .Single(z => z.CategoryName == counterCategoryName);
}
```

Comment: While testing this issue I have found that the new counters that have been added to the category are actually writing to the same memory space, which is the last counter that was originally added.

As a work around for this issue I have created a brand new category (i.e different name) and the counters all work as expect. Only issue will be if I wish to add a new counter after this I will need to do the same thing again.